# What is the Hessian of the Gaussian likelihood

Tags: normal-distribution, derivative, hessian, jacobian

I am trying to learn the fine differences between different methods of Kronecker factoring for approximate curvature (like [1], and [2]) which require taking the Hessian of the pre-activations of the last layer. [2] says that the pre-activation Hessian of the squared loss $\frac{(\hat{\mathbf{y}} - \mathbf{y})^2}{2} = I$ which makes sense because the first partial w.r.t. multiple independent output variables $\hat{\mathbf{y}}$ would be a vector of $\mathbf{\hat{y}} - \mathbf{y}$ and then expanding to the Hessian w.r.t. each element of $\hat{\mathbf{y}}$ would be $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \hat{y}_i \hat{y}_j}$ would be equal to $I$.

I would like to do the same thing for the Gaussian loss used in regression tasks which output a Gaussian likelihood, but I am unsure if I am doing it correctly.

###### Given the log Gaussian likelihood below parameters $(\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\sigma}) = \tau$, what are the Jacobian and Hessian? (assuming, as in the first case, $\mu, \sigma$ represent multiple outputs).

$$
-\log\Big( \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})^2}\Big) = \log \sigma + \frac{1}{2} \log 2\pi + \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x - \mu)^2
$$

The Jacobian would be the first partial derivatives of the negative log density with respect to the parameters of the distribution,
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}\log \sigma + \frac{1}{2} \log 2\pi + \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x - \mu)^2 &= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial\mathcal{N}}{\partial \mu}, & \frac{\partial\mathcal{N}}{\partial \sigma}\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{(x - \mu)}{\sigma^2}, & \frac{1}{\sigma} - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{\sigma^3}\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}

And the Hessian would be the second partial derivatives w.r.t each entry in the Jacobian,
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{N}}{\partial^2 \tau} &= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial^2\mathcal{N}}{\partial \mu\mu}, & \frac{\partial^2\mathcal{N}}{\partial \mu\sigma} \\ \frac{\partial^2\mathcal{N}}{\partial \sigma\mu}, & \frac{\partial^2\mathcal{N}}{\partial \sigma\sigma}\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{1}{\sigma^2}, & \frac{2(x - \mu)}{\sigma^3} \\
\frac{2(x - \mu)}{\sigma^3}, & -\frac{1}{\sigma^2} + 3\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{\sigma^4}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}

**Does this look correct?** What I cannot justify is why I do not have a 3 dimensional Hessian. The Jacobian of the squared loss (single output variable, multiple outputs) introduced above is a vector and then the Hessian is a 2 dimensional object of size $n \times n$.

In the Gaussian case we have two output variables, and also multiple outputs, so then would the Hessian of this Gaussian be $n \times n \times 4$, or $n \times n \times 2$?

[1] https://openreview.net/pdf?id=Skdvd2xAZ

[2] http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/botev17a/botev17a.pdf

Comment: I can't follow your final comments at all, because you have posited a situation with two parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma:$ thus, the Hessian will be a $2\times 2$ matrix.  Where do all these extra dimensions come from??

Comment: Oh sorry, the extra dimensions come from the fact that the $\mu, \sigma$ outputs are for multiple data instances. In the intro paragraph $y, \hat{y}$ are over multiple data instances which is why the Jacobian is a vector and the Hessian turns into a matrix. In that case, there is one output variable, but we have two, so there must be another dimension, but I am not sure if the Hessian should be $n \times n \times 2$ or $n \times n \times 4$. I will update hte question for clarity

Comment: @deltaskelta the last display looks similar to what I remember in my probability theory notes. I don't think there's a tremendous analytic difficulty in expressing $\mu$ as an activation function, i.e. $\mu(\beta) = f(\tau)$. However, you just need to take account of the chain rule. Expanding in matrix form should be the *last* step of the derivation for clarity. $\partial f / \partial \tau = \partial f / \partial \mu  \cdot\partial \mu / \partial \tau$. etc for higher dimensions and extra derivatives.

Comment: @AdamO so then would the final Hessian be $n \times n \times 4$? or $n \times n \times 2$?

Comment: @deltaskelta the hessian will not depend on $n$ at all - assuming $n$ is a sample size, nor will it be a tensor. It should be $p \times p$ where $p$ is the number of free parameters in the model.

Comment: but that is assuming I am differentiating w.r.t. the model parameters, and I am not. I am differentiating w.r.t. the output variables twice. If This was propagated via Hessian vector products with the chain rule then it would eventually be $p \times p$, but that is not what I am doing in the question

Comment: @deltaskelta well I'm not the only person confused by the question, and perhaps the whole approach is confused. If you can't explain what $\tau$ is this question is not answerable.

Comment: @AdamO $\tau$ is a shorthand for the two output variables $\mu, sigma$ because it was awkward to write the partial derivative in terms of two variables $\frac{\partial N}{\partial\tau}$ expands to $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial N}{\partial \mu} & \frac{\partial N}{\partial \sigma}  \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion is that you are directly applying a probabilistic result to a statistical sample.

That is, if your vector of observations $[Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n] \sim_{iid} \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then I believe you are considering that the "Jacobian of the sample" would be a tensor, i.e. the $n \times 2 \times 2$ vector of $\partial ^2 [Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n] / \partial ^2 \tau$. While technically true, in practice this doesn't make sense. Rather, we use the random sample to estimate the functionals of the Jacobian and gradient for a single observation. Your result for the gradient and Jacobian are correct for a single observation, i.e. for a probability case. The missing piece is how we use the random sample to *estimate* those functionals. The most straightforward application is to use the Mann Wold theorem. This gives you that if you have consistent estimators of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, you can just plug them into the functional and boom there's your estimate.

So using a random sample of size $n$, I would have as the Jacobian:

\begin{aligned}
\widehat{\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{N}}{\partial^2 \tau}} &= \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{1}{\hat{\sigma}^2}, & \frac{2(x - \hat{\mu})}{\hat{\sigma^3}} \\
\frac{2(x - \hat{\mu})}{\hat{\sigma^3}}, & -\frac{1}{\hat{\sigma^2}} + 3\frac{(x - \hat{\mu})^2}{\hat{\sigma}^4}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}

This is what some first year probability students (ahem myself in the past) would have called "putting hats on everything".

Comment: I was using $n$ meaning sample size and not the number of output layers. There are only two outputs in the model I described above $\mu$ and $\sigma$

Comment: @deltaskelta well I'm really at a loss of how or why you think $n$ should be in the dimensionality of the Jacobian. Is your confusion that, when you have a sample, you think a gradient is calculated *for each observation*?

Comment: My confusion is that in the initial paragraph, by my reasoning $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \hat{y}_i \partial \hat{y}_j}$ is the only way the the Hessian w.r.t. the squared loss becomes $I$. This implies that the indices $i, j$ are in the sample size $N$ as far as I can tell. I must be doing something wrong I guess but I can't see what it is

Comment: @deltaskelta hm, i try my hand one more time to answer but if it's still not your question I'll let someone else figure it out.

Comment: What you are saying may be correct, but then footnote 4 of page 2 of this paper (http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/botev17a/botev17a.pdf) MUST ONLY be true if there are multiple output variables. If there is only one output variable, then the Hessian, $I$ in the first paragraph would just be a scalar $1$. Does that sound right? If that is correct, then it was just confusing notation in the paper

Comment: @deltaskelta I don't think the paper's notation is confusing. What you are calling "output variables" are really parameters, a critical kind of Bayesian conflation. Anyway, suppose $X$ followed an exponential rule with only 1 parameter, then you're right the Hessian would be $1 \times 1$. There's nothing wrong with the matrix representation for the general case, even $p=1$.

Comment: The education I do or don't have is irrelevant. My last comment was meant to mean that I no longer expect it to be $n \times n$, but $d \times d$ where d is the number of output variables per input. The notation within the paper was confusing me because without bold faced vector notation, I usually tend to think of the squared error loss as having a single output per input. If that were the case, then where are the extra dimensions for $I$ coming from? Thats the point that was tripping me up